# JQuery Validation Plugin When Validation a field that has to be grouped and ungrouped

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a report that has a range date as its filter. The user has specified that each input has got to have its own validation message. So if the user enter two invalid dates, than I have two invalid messages, one for each input. But the user also wants messages when the validation fails because of the two inputs, i.e., if the start date is not earlier than the end date. Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Quick search
    $('input#email_search_list').quicksearch('#detailed-opt-out-report #detailed-opt-out-report-table tbody tr');

    // A custom method for validating the date range.
    $.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function() {
        var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
        return isDate(startDate) && isDate(endDate) ? Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(endDate) : true;
    });

    // Another custom method for validating if at least one of the fields has value.
    $.validator.addMethod("bothEmpty", function() {
        return $("#startDate").val() || $("#endDate").val();
    });

    var form = $('#frmdetailedoptoutreport');
    form.validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.blockUI({fadeIn:0, message: '<h1>Por favor, aguarde...</h1>'});
            form.submit();
        }, 
        rules: {
            startDate: {
                date: true,
                dateRange: true,
                bothEmpty: true
            },
            endDate: {
                date: true,
                dateRange: true,
                bothEmpty: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            alert("oi");
            form.find(".errorContainer").append(error);
        },
        messages: {
            startDate: {
                date: "Por favor, especifique uma data inicial válida.",
                bothEmpty: "É obrigatório inserir pelo menos um filtro na busca.",
                dateRange: "A data final não pode ser menor que a data inicial."
            },
            endDate: {
                date: "Por favor, especifique uma data final  válida."
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
    <form id="frmdetailedoptoutreport" name="frmdetailedoptoutreport" method="post" action="detailedoptoutreport">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="1" />
        <p>
            <label for="startDate">Selecione intervalo de data:</label>
            <input class="datapicker" id="startDate" type="text" name="startDate" value="" maxlength="10" />
            a
            <input class="datapicker" id="endDate" type="text" name="endDate" value="" maxlength="10" />
        </p>
        <div class="errorContainer"></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" onclick="restartPagination();" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The restartPagination and isDate JS functions:

```
function restartPagination() {
    $("#page").val(1);
}

function isDate(txtDate) {
    if (!txtDate) {
        return false;
    }

    // Declare Regex
    var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
    var dtArray = txtDate.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?
    if (dtArray == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Checks for dd/MM/yyyy format.
    dtDay = dtArray[1];
    dtMonth = dtArray[3];
    dtYear = dtArray[5];

    if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12) {
        return false;
    } else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) {
        return false;
    } else if ((dtMonth == 4 || dtMonth == 6 || dtMonth == 9 || dtMonth == 11) && dtDay == 31) {
        return false;
    } else if (dtMonth == 2) {
        var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
        if (dtDay > 29 || (dtDay == 29 && !isleap)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, this code gives me two behaviours that I do not want. The first behaviour is that the validations are executed twice. Ok, if I cut off the validation in one of the fields I would have this solved, but if I do this the input does not get the CSS error class that is one of my user specification (color the input that has a problem).

The second behaviour that I don't want is the message being duplicated. Again, if I cut off the validation from one of the inputs I would have my problem solved, but again the input would lose the CSS error class. If I use jquery group validator, I get one message, but when I have, i.e., both fields with invalid dates and as explained above two messages, that second message overrides the first one.

So, here's my question, does anyone know how to put the error class in the other field if I call the validations in just one field or knows how to not duplicate messages when the message is for a validation that failed because of the two inputs?

Comment: Can you provide the html code or a jsfiddle example ?

Comment: @Charles Jourdan, finally, I got to insert my HTML code.

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/8Ur8N/7. I'm not sure I used it the right way.